# html - do images in a overflow:hidden div still load in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 1x1 image (for tracking) that is in a div with overflow:hidden (appears in the hidden part of the div).

Will that image still load in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it will load in all (major) browsers

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (ignoring obvious cases like text-only browsers).

You could also apply `display: none;` to the `<img>` to achieve the same result.

Comment: This is not true. `display:none` forces image not to load

Comment: In which browsers? Chrome definitely requests the image even when `display:none` is set. See for yourself: http://jsbin.com/ixucix/edit (I used the Network tab in the Chrome dev tools).

Comment: 'display: none' is a common technique for preloading images other than using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work in all major browsers, (though ie can be screwy with most things) The display none also works but i wouldnt advise it since if your not using it why load it.